# Autonomous system corresponding to flow: $\Phi(t, x) = e^t(1 + x) − 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that $\Phi(t, x) = e^t(1 + x) − 1$ is a flow, i.e., it satisfies
$$\Phi(0, x) = x, \;
\Phi(t + s, x) = \Phi(t,\Phi(s, x)), \; x ∈ M, \; s, t + s ∈ I_x.$$

Can you find an autonomous system corresponding to this flow?

**QUESTION:** I have managed to show that $\Phi$ satisfies those equations.
But I couldn´t find an autonomous system corresponding to this flow, how can I find it and how it would it look like? I am familiar with the way of solving an autonomous system but I don´t how do it in reverse in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given $x_0$, we have that:

$$x(t) = \Phi(t, x_0)= e^t (1+x_0) - 1.$$
Notice that:

$$\frac{d x(t)}{dt } =e^t (1+x_0) = x(t) + 1.$$

Therefore:
$$\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = x(t)+1,$$
is the autonomous system you are looking for.